# Displaying error messages when two forms are integrated in the same magento page

Tags: magento

I have the login form and register form, integrated in the same page. ie, in the login page itself.

I am having a problem in showing the error messages, as if error occurs in any one of the forms, then the error messages are displayed in both the login and register sections.

for example, suppose if we provide wrong login data to login, then the error message is displayed on the top of both the login and register forms, since both the forms are in the same page.

If we try to register with an already existing email address, then also, error message saying email already exists, displayed on the top of login form and register form.

My requirement is that i need to display the error message only in the corresponding form.

In order to integrate both login and register form in to the login page itself, i changed the file `\app\design\frontend\anz\default\layout\customer.xml` and it is as follows

Layout for customer login page

```
<customer_account_login translate="label">
    <label>Customer Account Login Form</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml"/>
    </reference>


    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before" translate="label">
        <label>Form Fields Before</label>
        <!--action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action-->
        <action method="setElementClass"><value>rewards</value></action>
    </block>
    <block type="enterprise_customer/form" template="customer/form/userattributes.phtml" name="customer_form_user_attributes">
        <action method="setFormCode"><code>customer_account_create</code></action>
        <action method="setEntityModelClass"><code>customer/customer</code></action>
    </block>
    <block type="enterprise_customer/form" template="customer/form/userattributes.phtml" name="customer_form_address_user_attributes">
        <action method="setFormCode"><code>customer_register_address</code></action>
        <action method="setEntityModelClass"><code>customer/address</code></action>
    </block>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="customer/form/register.phtml">
            <action method="append"><block>customer.form.register.fields.before</block><alias>form_fields_before</alias></action>
            <action method="append"><block>customer_form_user_attributes</block></action>
            <action method="append"><block>customer_form_address_user_attributes</block></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <update handle="customer_form_template_handle"/>



</customer_account_login>
```

I am a newbie in magento. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a simple way to achieve the requirement. There may be better ways to do this, but I think this one is simple.

I had created a hidden variable and I put those hidden variable in forms to identify which form is submitted. These hidden variable is passed as a parameter after completing the corresponding action. Then I provided an if block to display the messages according to the parameter value.

I did this all by overriding the Mage Customer module.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a little bit. Please tell me where your forms are rendered?

```
<customer_account_login translate="label">
    <label>Customer Account Login Form</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>

    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before" translate="label">
        <label>Form Fields Before</label>
        <!--action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action-->
        <action method="setElementClass"><value>rewards</value></action>
    </block>
    <block type="enterprise_customer/form" template="customer/form/userattributes.phtml" name="customer_form_user_attributes">
        <action method="setFormCode"><code>customer_account_create</code></action>
        <action method="setEntityModelClass"><code>customer/customer</code></action>
    </block>
    <block type="enterprise_customer/form" template="customer/form/userattributes.phtml" name="customer_form_address_user_attributes">
        <action method="setFormCode"><code>customer_register_address</code></action>
        <action method="setEntityModelClass"><code>customer/address</code></action>
    </block>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml"/>
        <block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="customer/form/register.phtml">
            <action method="append"><block>customer.form.register.fields.before</block><alias>form_fields_before</alias></action>
            <action method="append"><block>customer_form_user_attributes</block></action>
            <action method="append"><block>customer_form_address_user_attributes</block></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <update handle="customer_form_template_handle"/>
</customer_account_login>
```

Comment: I used your code and it gives the output in the same way as before.
The forms I am using are located in
\app\design\frontend\anz\default\template\customer\form\login.phtml
\app\design\frontend\anz\default\template\customer\form\register.phtml
and the post action of login form is /customer/account/loginPost/
and the post action of register form is /customer/account/createpost/

Comment: I suppose you should add form key parameter to the form you have if you don't have it. Moreover I think that you add success message to your session, but not to form.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Magento Theming :-)

First, it's generally a better practice to use local.xml layout file under your custom theme (it's not there by default, it's for the end implementer to use). This way, you won't have to  needlessly merge changes into customer.xml to keep it up to date.

In your local.xml, you can use the `<update />` directive to include the layout update xml from one handle into another (which is effectively what you are doing already):

```
<customer_account_login>
    <update handle="customer_account_create" />
</customer_account_login>
```

You will need to customize your create template `customer/form/register.phtml` and remove its `<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>` call.

Comment: I changed the customer.xml with default code and created a new file \app\design\frontend\anz\default\layout\local.xml and in that local.xml file, i placed your code, but now i can only see the login form in login page. My requirement is that i want both the login and register forms in the login page itself. i would be pleased if you provide me any useful url regarding this.